# Can't locate specific package

Tags: software-installation, libav

I'm completely new to ubuntu. 
I would like to install [this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libavcodec57)

But when I try to install it using commandline

```
apt-get install libavcodec57
```

the package is not found. So my question:

Is this packet located at any other source, is it not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04, what is it?
How can I install this package?

Comment: Are you trying to expand codec support with libav / avconv under Trusty Tahr?

Answer (score 0):

You can either install the source package ffmpeg, or follow the instructions at the bottom of the [libavcodec57](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libavcodec57) page that corresponds with your particular architecture. From the download page:

> You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to >your /etc/apt/sources.list like this:
>
> deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main universe
>
> Replacing cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu with the mirror in question.

It appears that downloading the binary package using apt-get or synaptic is not possible.